# Efficient calculation of Sobel gradient magnitude

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I'm currently using this code to calculate the magnitude of the Sobel gradient:

```
sobel_x = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im), cv.IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1)
sobel_y = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im), cv.IPL_DEPTH_16S, 1)
cv.Sobel(im, sobel_x, 1, 0, 3)
cv.Sobel(im, sobel_y, 0, 1, 3)

width, height = cv.GetSize(im)
for i in range(width*height):
    x, _, _, _ = cv.Get1D(sobel_x, i)
    y, _, _, _ = cv.Get1D(sobel_y, i)
    px = int(math.sqrt(x*x + y*y))
    cv.Set1D(sobel, i, px)
```

It's simple enough, but it's not very efficient, because I'm accessing each pixel one by one.  I was hoping of a better way to do this in OpenCV:

```
sobel_x2 = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im), cv.IPL_DEPTH_32S, 1)
sobel_y2 = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im), cv.IPL_DEPTH_32S, 1)
sobel_2  = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im), cv.IPL_DEPTH_32S, 1)
cv.Mul(sobel_x, sobel_x, sobel_x2)
cv.Mul(sobel_y, sobel_y, sobel_y2)
cv.Add(sobel_x2, sobel_y2, sobel_2)
```

Here I'm just squaring the images and adding them.  It uses more memory but should be faster because now some operations will be done in parallel.  What I'm stuck on is there's no element-wise square root function (`cv.Sqrt` seems to only work with scalars).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already noted, `cv.Sqrt()` only accepts a scalar in the Python bindings. Since there is an equivalent function, `cv::sqrt()`, that performs an element-wise square-root, it should also be in the mostly auto-generated Python bindings. Perhaps this is a bug in the version of OpenCV that you are using.

Regardless, you should be able to use `cv.Pow()` to get the same result:

```
cv.Pow(src, dst, 0.5)
```

This is likely not as fast as `cv.Sqrt()` would be, but should still dramatically outperform an element-wise computation.

Comment: The Python bindings wrap the C interface, not the C++ interface.  So `cv.sqrt` is a wrapper for `cvSqrt` (not `cv::sqrt`), which is a function that accepts a scalar.  Nevertheless, I will use `cv.Pow`.  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Good catch. It looks like this discrepancy between the C/Python and C++ APIs is being fixed with [cv.Sqrt() in OpenCV 2.3](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=sqrt#sqrt). Also, please accept my answer if it solved your problem.